# One to Many not working on Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have three models that are related. First I have User that belongs to a Role. On the other hand, Role has many roles. Role belongs to many permissions and Permissions belongs to many Role. I am using the AuthServiceProvider as suggested by jeffrey way of laracast. But the problem now, when I want to fetch all the permissions of a User I am having error which is, "Call to a member function getKey() on boolean". Can someone please help me on this. Please refer to the codes below.

User.php

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}

public function assignRole($role)
{
    return $this->roles()->save(
        Role::whereName($role)->firstOrFail()
    );
}

public function hasRole($role)
{
    if(is_string($role)){
        return $this->role->contains('name', $role);
    }

    return !! $role->intersect($this->role)->count();

}
```

Role.php

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission');
    }

    public function givePermissions(Permission $permission)
    {
        return $this->permissions()->save($permission);
    }
}
```

Permission.php

```
class Permission extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

AuthServiceProvider

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);

    //get all permissions
    foreach ($this->getPermissionTo() as $permission ) {

        $gate->define($permission->name, function($user) use ($permission){
            return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
        });
    }
}

public function getPermissionTo()
{
    return Permission::with('roles')->get();
}
```

and lastly, heres the user table that has a foreign key of role_id

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

        $table->string('id_no')->unique()->index();
        $table->string('u_first_name');
        $table->string('u_middle_name');
        $table->string('u_last_name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');

        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

roles table

```
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('label')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

permissions table

```
   Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('label')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

permission_role table

```
  Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('permission_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('permissions')
              ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('role_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('roles')
              ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
    });
```

Comment: Please add in the full error message you see, including line number and file name.

Comment: @NirajShah Heres the complete error 1/1
FatalErrorException in Collection.php line 240:
Call to a member function getKey() on boolean
in Collection.php line 240

Comment: Can please someone help me on this. Thanks

Comment: The issue could be to do with the way the columns are labeled in the tables. Make sure you have defined the primary key if it's not the default ```id```  column. Even better, update question with table structure.

Comment: @NirajShah okay upon checking my tables primary key are all set correctly. Please see my updated tables including permissions and roles

Comment: @NirajShah can you please check my updated code again. I really need to work on this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm stumped. Does the full error trace reveal any information about what function could be triggering the error?

Answer (score 1):

In the line: `return !! $role->intersect($this->role)->count();`, the part that says `$this->role` is probably not returning a collection, which is why you're getting this error. In Collection.php there's a method that iterates through all the items in a collection you send through the intersection method that gets the primary key of it. Because you're not sending a collection to the `intersect()` method, it tries to use the method getKey() in a boolean. Try:

```
return !! $role->intersect($this->role->get())->count();
```